Selinux module to open fm radio application access to /dev/fm
I am new in magisk and selinux. Please help me write module,which allow to decompiled fm radio app get access to /dev/fm. I dont want to use setenforce 0,because my device will become more Invulnerable. I learn,what for solving of my problem it enough write selinux rule and the best way for this in my opinion,create magisk module for this. So i asked chatgpt about selinux rules,but it advices almost not help me,except information about reason of error,i.e details about permissive issue. when I executed dmesg |grep radio,i stopped on one message:
pid=2521 comm="android.fmradio" name="fm" dev="tmpfs" ino=8698 scontext=u:r:priv_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:fm_device:s0 tclass=chr_file permissive=0
After chatgpt help and googling I started to create magisk module. First of all I created file sepolicy.rule with text:
allow priv_app fm_device chr_file { read write ioctl open }

Also my module contains module.prop. and nothing else. Before I tried use another selinux rule,so I reinstall module via adb two or probably three times (may be more). I tried to install magisk module via adb shell su (my device have api 27 and it's rooted)
magisk --install-module /sdcard/fm_radio_sepolicy.zip
It seems,what installation of module was successfully. After device reboot my module is visible in list of modules in magisk app,and it switch on,but my rule was not apply. It seems,what the  content of file /sbin/.magisk/preinit/sepolicy.rule was the same,as my rule. Help me,why my rule was not apply. May be my module should contains other files,except this two files? Thanks everybody very much for any help.

Whether someone know reply on my question,except silence? I reported issue to magisk,because,it seems,it's magisk issue.
